# Going back to previous git commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and finally starting to learn git.

I'm trying to follow a tutorial, but I hit a snag and accidentally did a step out of order.  So now when I'm trying to do a "rails db:migrate" I'm getting error messages that columns already exist, and I can't continue the tutorial.

The last time I ran a "git commit" to my branch, the app was stable.

I'd like to get the local version of my app to go back to the last version I committed to git.

I haven't done this before, how can this be done?  I've looked up the git documentation, but being new to this, it's been pretty confusing and I don't want to mess anything up.

Comment: If a migration gets stuck you'll need to comment out the part that is already migrated (see where your error hit), than run `rails db:migrate` again to finish your migration. Uncomment your migration and your set. If you want to make sure that it runs in it's entirety you can than `rails db:rollback` and rerun the (uncommented) migration.

Comment: @Johan Wentholt Thank you! This seems to be exactly what I needed.  It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

How careful your commit operations are, sometimes you may have included files that you forgot to include in your commit or accidentally included them, or you may have provided incomplete information in the commit message. In this case you can use the **git commit** command with the **--amend** option to **re-commit** your last commit. If you just want to change the commit message, you can run git commit with the **amend -m** option. If you want to add or remove files from the last commit, you can do the staging first with the **git add** and **git rm** commands mentioned earlier in the commit section.

Answer (score 0):

To move though the git tree, you use the `git checkout <branch>` command. You can check the hash for the previous command by using `git log`. You can use this to go to a previous commit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to roll back to a previous commit. Just update your migration file to use `table_exists?` and/or `column_exists?` directives.

If you're creating an entirely new table, it'd be used like this:

```
class CreateSomeCoolThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    unless table_exists?(:some_cool_things)
      create_table :some_cool_things do |t|
        ...
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    if table_exists?(:some_cool_things)
      drop_table :some_cool_things
    end
  end
end
```

And if you're just adding new columns to an existing table, you could do this:

```
class AddSomeAttributeToWhatevers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :whatevers, :some_attribute, :string unless column_exists? :whatevers, :some_attribute
  end

  def down
    remove_column :whatevers, :some_attribute if column_exists? :whatevers, :some_attribute
  end
end
```

Safe-guarding your migrations in this way is just a good practice to get in the habit of anyways.

Comment: great to know, thank you! I definitely want to be sure that I'm following best practices.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran a migration on your database, which created the column you are getting the error about.
Most likely you ran the migration, but did not rollback and checked out a commit before you generated the migration.

If that's your case then reverting to a previous commit will have the same error since your database is at fault.

**In order to fix this you need to manually delete the column and run the migration again.**

After you run the migration, your schema_migration files will contain the latest migration, and that should fix it for the future (sort of).

Comment: Thank you, this is great info to have as I'm learning this process